# mongo.h: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, gcc, mongo-c-driver

I get the mongo-c-driver from official website, as follows:

```
$git https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
$cd mongo-c-driver
$./autogen.sh
$ make
$ sudo make install
Deal.c:2:19: fatal error: mongo.h: No such file or directory
```

However,when I run my C file named "Deal.c" like this:

```
gcc -o Deal Deal.c -l /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lmongoc
Error:#include "mongo.h"
                     ^ compilation terminated.
```

My system version: is Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: the headers called mongoc.h not mongo.h

Comment: I have tried the headers mongoc.h instead of mongo.h

Comment: but it doesn't work, Error: mongoc.h:not such file or directory

Comment: it also seems to install to `include/mongoc-${API_VERSION}` where the current version appears to be 1.0 so the full path should be `mongoc-1.0/mongoc.h`

Comment: In fact,if it does work,I would never ask such question here! @user1937198

Comment: Maybe，I know the reason

Comment: @user2270421 , were you able to solve the issue? I am stuck at similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you are missing the path to the headers as well as the locations of the libraries. One option would be to install to the same prefix that your platform uses, such as:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

If that is not an option, then you can update your Makefile to include the proper library and include path as such:

```
gcc Deal.c -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0
```

This will typically be done automatically for you by using `pkg-config` on Unix'like systems as such:

```
gcc Deal.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0)
```

However, if you install into a non-standard path such as /usr/local, then you will need to let `pkg-config` know where to find the `libmongoc-1.0.pc` file, such as:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig gcc Deal.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, using the prefix ``--prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64`` where Fedora stores libs and headers worked. However, using the default install location ``/usr/local/`` still doesn't work. I'm confused, because the libs are all in ``/usr/local/lib`` and headers are in ``/usr/local/include``. It compiles like before, but it still complains that it can't find ``libmongoc-1.0.so.0`` even though it exists. Any ideas?

Comment: ``[raspberries@localhost mongo-c-driver]$ ./configure && make && sudo make install``  

``[raspberries@localhost mongo-c-driver]$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0``  

``-I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/include/libbson-1.0 -L/usr/local/lib -lrt -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0``

Comment: ``[raspberries@localhost C-mongo]$ gcc -o test test.c -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/include/libbson-1.0 -L/usr/local/lib -lrt -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0``  
``[raspberries@localhost C-mongo]$ ./test``  
``./test: error while loading shared libraries: libmongoc-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory``  
``[raspberries@localhost C-mongo]$ ls /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0``  
``/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0``

Comment: Sorry I missed this. But the reason is that your dynamic linker cannot locate the library when the application is started. (/etc/ld.so.conf will tell you where it is configured to look). Otherwise, you can just do LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./test

Comment: I should note that this happened to me both with mongo-c-driver-1.6.3 (and passing those flags to ./configure worked) and with mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.2 where cmake requires -DLIBBSON_DIR and -DLIBMONGOC_DIR